# Search SQLite database returns empty cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, search

I am using a searchView to get a query to search database with a string,  the Cursor does not return as null but is empty.

The call to search from my search activity (which is a ListActivity implementing SearchView.OnQueryTextListener):

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //handleIntent(intent);
        Log.d("LIST ACTIVITY SEARCH", "onQueryTextCahanged called: "+ newText);
        Cursor c = data.getWordMatches(newText, null);

        Log.d("LISTACTIVITY", "CURSOR QUERY ROWS/COLS = "+ c.getCount()+" "+c.getColumnCount());

        //now set bind cursor data to list view using custim ItemAdpter class
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(ViewListOfTests.this, c);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        return false;
    }
```

And the search method in SQLite Databasetaking the String query from method above:

```
/*
     * methods to search database with String query form searchable widget intent 
    *  in ViewListOfDives ListActivity search bar. Each search returns a cursor which is set to adpter
    *  in ViewListOfYesys List Activity
    */

    public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns){

        String selection = database.KEY_TESTNAME + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"}; //wildcard *

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);


    }//end getWordMatches



    private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String[] columns) {

        // return cursor form params passed getWordMatches(Styring query) from search widget ListActivity

        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);

        dbHelperObject = new DbHelper(ourContext);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(dbHelperObject.getReadableDatabase(), columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if(cursor == null){
            return null;
        }else if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }

        return cursor;




    }//end query
```

The else if code executes here returning an empty cursor :

```
else if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
                cursor.close();
                return null;
```

Any input appreciated! 
Ciaran

Comment: try `String selection = database.KEY_TESTNAME + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"%"+query+"%"};` just to know where the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, seems i was passing the wrong parameter to the curosr.rawQuery().
 I was passing a ref to dataBase helper object getReadableDB call:

```
Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

When I replaced this parameter with the database object it worked fine:

```
SQLiteDatabase ourDataBase = ourDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

Cursor cursor = builder.query(ourDataBase, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

The training documentation stated pass the former mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase() but this did not seem to work, not why.http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html

Answer (score 1):

instead of this :

```
if(cursor == null){
    return null;
}else if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
cursor.close();
   return null;
}

return cursor;
```

use this:

```
if(cursor == null){
    return null;
}else{
     cursor.moveToFirst();
}

return cursor;
```

Comment: Tried both, keep getting a cursor with 0 rows and 13 columns. When looking at cursor in Debugger I see SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM tests WHERE (name LIKE ?). When the ListAdpter is set with this cursor the entire database is displayed..

Comment: Although a new cursor is returned from the search, after i call the setListAdpter(adp) with the new adapter from new cursor, the nCreate() method seems to be called again and therefore calls the original Adpter with a cursor donating all results

Comment: If you retrieve 0 rows so your query is wrong, or you do not select your items correctly. make sure your select query is right.